# VS 2010 intellisense not working for upconverted project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, intellisense

We have a very big C++ solution with several projects for which intellisense works perfectly in Visual Studio 2008, but not at all in Visual Studio 2010 (not even for structs defined in the same file where they are used).  I've verified that intellisense does work in VS 2010 for other projects on my machine.  I've tried importing one of the problematic projects from a brand-new solution with no success.  Re-building the project files from scratch seems promising, but it would require days of work to follow that path, with no guarantee of success at the end.  Any alternative suggestions are welcome.  The actual error message I get is:

"Intellisense: 'No additional information available'(See 'Troubleshooting IntelliSense in C++ Projects' for further help.)

I've tried that, but there's basically only one suggestion on the MSDN webpage, to make sure "stdafx.h" on the include path, but we're not using precompiled headers and don't include it from anywhere, so I'm pretty sure that's not the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Have you deleted all of the generated database (.ncb and .sdf) files?  Corrupted database files is the most likely cause of Visual Studio failing to display IntelliSense.

Comment: I did try that, and as I mentioned, I also tried using the project in a brand-new solution, for which there couldn't have been any corruption issues; the .ncb (VS 2008) and .sdf (VS 2010) files are associated with solutions, not projects.

Answer (score 1):

Intellisense was not included as a component of Visual Studio 2010 for C++/CLI. Unfortunately, it seems they are not going to support it soon either. This is an incredible detriment, as i find myself having to open VS2005 on occasion to simply find an object member.

Here is Microsoft's release on the subject:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/03/03/10136696.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the info.  However, intellisense really should be working on my project as it is entirely native C++, not managed C++ or C++/CLI.

Comment: I completely agree that it should be working. But i do not believe it was supported for C++ at all, only VB and i think C#. :(

Comment: I've confirmed that it does work on other native C++ projects